# Why there is a resistor soldered across output (green) and excitation (black) in a S-Beam load cell?

Tags: load-cell

[image]

As the photo displayed above, it is a S-Beam load cell. We selected the same color of wires that connect the header of the load cell. As we can see, there is a resistor soldered across output (green) and excitation (black). Why a resistor should be soldered here?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is for offset (zero) compensation.

Most Strain-Gauges are relatively low-impedance devices.  Values generally range from 200R through about 1.2k for each of the 4 resistors in the gauges.

You would use a high-value resistor to do this compensation.

Answer (score 1):

That's a 200kOhm (red/black/yellow) or 2MOhm (red/black/green) resistor.

The only reason I see to put that 2MO resistor in parallel with a load cell resistor is to have some fine-tuning over the output value.